# How to Execute a Stored Procedure in a Join Statement SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to call a stored procedure in a join statement of the Select Query.

For example,

```
Select * 
from test
left join test1 on GetID(test.id)=test1.id
```

The idea is to match one to many relationship.

The structure of tables would be

Table: Test

```
ID Name
1  abc
2  te
```

Table: Test1

```
Id TestID Name
1   1      xxx
2   1      yyy
3   1      zzz
4   2      aaa
```

Stored procedure:

```
Create procedure GETID
    @id int
as
begin
    select top 1 id 
    from test1 
    where testid = @id
end
```

Comment: Change your stored procedure to a scalar function

Comment: That worked, Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a scalar function instead.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETID
(
@id int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
return (select top 1 id from test1 where testid=@id)
END
```

Or, review methods in post: [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Use cross apply (or outer apply), which executes once on right side of query.
Or, use row_number() over partition to rank the group rows and select based on rank.

```
declare @test table (id int, name varchar(100))
insert into @test (id, name) values (1, 'abc')
insert into @test (id, name) values (1, 'te')
declare @test1 table (id int, testid int, name varchar(100))
insert into @test1 (id, testid, name) values (1, 1, 'xxx')
insert into @test1 (id, testid, name) values (2, 1, 'yyy')
insert into @test1 (id, testid, name) values (3, 1, 'zzz')
insert into @test1 (id, testid, name) values (4, 2, 'aaa')

Select * from @test t
cross apply (select top 1 * from @test1
          where testid = t.id
          order by id) -- change group order as needed
          as t1
```

Comment: Though this is correct, I would suggest using an inline table-valued function instead of a scalar function for performance gain.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the stored procedure into an inline table-valued function or you can put the query inside an `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM test t
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 id
    FROM test1
    WHERE testid = t.testid
)x
```